# Linq remove only one item if there are duplicate

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have 5 numbers i.e.: 1 1 1 2 3;
I have to sum them except the minimum number, but I can remove it only one time (if the minimum occurs more than one time I have to maintain the rest). How can I do it with Linq? I thought:

```
var min = nums.Min();
var minSum = nums.Where(x => x != min).Sum();
```

But it remove all the 1s from the lists. I need a way to go out from the where if there's more than 1 occurence.

All this with Linq if it's possible.

Comment: Are there any other criteria? Like are you looking for a very fast implementation or the best readable or the fewest code? Just asking to not answer in the wrong direction.

Comment: For curiosity can I see the fastest implementation?

Comment: The fastest implementation is to use casual `for` loop (but for such a small bunch of items it won't be significant improvement).

Comment: Example please? What do you mean by "casual" for loop?

Comment: Sth like this:
`long sum = 0L; int min = Int32.MaxValue; for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) { sum += nums[i]; if (min > nums[i]) min = nums[i]; } sum =- min;` (assuming input data has at least  one element)
`For` loop is faster than linq for iterating arrays.
What's more, it iterates only once the input data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple solution would be the following, but would iterate the collection twice.

```
var nums = new int[]{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var minSum = nums.Sum() - nums.Min();
```

For a solution that only iterates the collection once using Linq you could write:

```
var nums = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var minSum = 
    nums.Aggregate(
        new {
            Min = int.MaxValue,
            Sum = 0
        },
        (accumulator, i) => new {
            Min = Math.Min(i, accumulator.Min),
            Sum = accumulator.Sum + i
        }, (accumulator) => accumulator.Sum - accumulator.Min);
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a one liner which even works if your array is empty

```
int[] nums = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int minSum = nums.OrderBy(x =>x).Skip(1).Sum();
```

Comment: Yep wanted to post that too but was afraid of the immediate "this is too slow" comments.

Answer (score 5):

Though [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273963/5528593) already seems very well, it still needs to iterate the list twice. Once to find the minium and once to find the sum.

So I just show a more verbose but therefor faster implementation:

```
var nums = new int[]{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int sum = 0;
int min = int.MaxValue;
foreach (int i in nums)
{
    sum += i;
    if (i < min) min = i;
}
if (nums.Length > 0) sum -= min;
```

I'm not sure if a `for` loop maybe faster than `foreach`, but I think that difference should not really be measurable.

---

For pwas comment I add the `for` version again:

```
for(int i=0; i<nums.Length; i++)
{
    int j = nums[i];
    sum += j;
    if (j < min) min = j;
}
if (nums.Length > 0) sum -= min;
```

Comment: `for` is about twice faster: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/

Comment: It is also worth to remember to make `sum` of type `long` - if we do not know to big data is :)

Comment: @pwas thx for the link, I will do some tests for myself. But at first glance it seems that it's only true for `List<int>`, not for `int[]`. And I guess that has to do with branch prediction or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var nums = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };

var list = nums.ToList();
list.Remove(nums.Min());
var minSum = list.Sum();
```